# I am gettinng Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ExpoInAppPurchases.default.connectAsync

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase, expo

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ExpoInAppPurchases.default.connectAsync')]
- node_modules\expo-in-app-purchases\build\InAppPurchases.js:15:7 in connectAsync
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:274:30 in invoke
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:135:28 in invoke
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:170:17 in PromiseImpl$argument_0
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:45:7 in tryCallTwo
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:200:23 in doResolve
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:66:12 in Promise
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:169:31 in PromiseImpl$argument_0
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:192:38 in enqueue
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:219:8 in exports.async
- node_modules\expo-in-app-purchases\build\InAppPurchases.js:15:7 in connectAsync
* http://192.168.0.5:19001/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:149253:78 in componentDidMount$
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:274:30 in invoke
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:135:28 in invoke
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:145:19 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:25 in setImmediate$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:146:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:194:17 in _callImmediatesPass
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:458:30 in callImmediates
* [native code]:null in callImmediates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:407:6 in __callImmediates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:143:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:142:17 in __guard$argument_0
* [native code]:null in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```